# Lanzador de Aplicaciones en Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Quiero hacer un acceso directo de xampp en ubuntu 20.10 pero a pesar de que me aparece la aplicación para ejecutarla no lo hace. les muestro:

al darle doble click al `.desktop` me lo abre como block de notas:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Xampp Manager
Comment=Manage XAMPP
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application;Development;Web
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

estos son los permisos:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 charlie charlie   228 jun  4 05:19 xampp_control_panel.desktop
```

y en la pestaña de permisos le tengo permitir ejecutar el archivo como un programa

no sé como hacerlo funcionar.

Gracias